Flutter platform exception 10
I'm facing a problem with Firebase Google Sign-in in my Flutter app. When I run the app in debug mode using wireless debugging and sign in with Google, it works fine without any errors. However, when I create a release build and run it, I encounter a "PlatformException(10)" error.
Could you please help me troubleshoot this issue?
i have added proper sha-1 and sha-256 key ,properly added google-service.json file in android/app folder

Have you added sha-1 for release certificate on Firebase Console?

not sure but u may try this. in ur  android/app/build.gradle ---> buildTypes {
release {
signingConfig = signingConfigs.release  // use release instead of debug
}
}
